# Hight accuracy first epochs

Tags: python, python-3.x, classification, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I’m new in the ML community, I hade some fun with the hello world exercises and others MNIST with python and tensorflow. But now (of course) I want to practice on my own data. [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rkFZ.jpg)

So I would like to use a very simple model (for now) already used for the cat and dog dataset (you can find the code here : https://thedatafrog.com/fr/articles/dogs-vs-cats/). But instead of the cad and dog.zip dataset I use my own dataset.
[resume-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ40q.png)

My dataset is about 3 000 images belonging in 2 classes (Cephalophe and Potamochere (some species from the tropical forest of Gabon  cf images below). I found those images on my videos from camera trap, I’ve made a little code **scraping** 15 images from a video of 6 sec. So some of my images are quite similar. And I have about 150 images from each classes **scraped** on google images.
But when I run my code, I have a very high accuracy on the very first epochs (as you can see in the images below). And at the end I have :  loss: 0.1189 - acc: 0.9578 - val_loss: 0.4246 - val_acc: 0.8928. But still my model can’t predict anything.
[epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkyU6.png)

My guess is that my training and test sets are too similar, so my model is not really trained. But maybe I’m wrong, so I’m asking for your help and tips.
In the below images you can find some images from my code.
[curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnhAN.png)

Sorry for bad English (any French fellows here ?) and sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Hello, I'm the author of the article you're quoting. To train a network to classify images with a limited dataset, I would suggest you to use transfer learning, as explained here: https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/image-recognition-transfer-learning/. Difficult to say why your network does not learn... one would have to do a detailed debugging. But I'm sure you'll have more luck with transfer learning: just make sure to only train the classifier part of the network as explained in the post. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Rob In,  Can you show your full code here?

Comment: @Rob In, Did you use Data Augmentation using `ImageDataGenerator`. Sample code can be like, `imgdatagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1/255., 
    horizontal_flip = True, 
    zoom_range = 0.3, 
    rotation_range = 15.,
    validation_split = 0.1,
)`. If not, please try that because, that will improve the Generalizing Capability of the Model. You can also try Transfer Learning. Also, What exactly do you mean by `But still my model can’t predict anything`. Can you share the code where you are trying to `Predict`.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you say `can't predict anything`, does it mean your Model can't `Predict` on `New Data` or on `Test Data`?

   a. If your Model doesn't `predict` well on New Data, it means that our Model is not trained on such images. To mitigate this, you need to add many such new Images as part of Training Data

   b. If your Model doesn't `predict` well on Test Data, your Training Data is not representing all the combinations of Images. To mitigate this, you can combine both `Train` and `Test` data, shuffle the `Data` randomly and then partition them to `Train` and `Test`.
2. Looking at your `Training Loss` and `Validation Loss` and considering the fact that `Model` is not Predicting well on unseen data, best approach is to use `Data Augmentation`. Sample code for implementing `Data Augmentation` using Keras `ImageDataGenerator` is shown below:

   `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
       featurewise_center=False, samplewise_center=False,
       featurewise_std_normalization=False, samplewise_std_normalization=False,
       zca_whitening=False, zca_epsilon=1e-06, rotation_range=40, width_shift_range=0.2,
       height_shift_range=0.2, brightness_range=0.8, shear_range=0.4, zoom_range=0.7,
       channel_shift_range=0.3, fill_mode='nearest', cval=0.0, horizontal_flip=True,
       vertical_flip=True, rescale=None, preprocessing_function=None,
       data_format=None, validation_split=0.0, dtype=None
   )`
3. As mentioned by Colin Bernet, you can use Transfer Learning as you have limited Dataset, using [this link](https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/image-recognition-transfer-learning/). Sample code for Transfer Learning is shown below:

`x = keras.layers.Flatten()(conv_model.output)`

`# three hidden layers`

`x = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)`

`x = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)`

`x = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)`

`# final softmax layer with two categories (dog and cat)`

`predictions = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)`

`# creating the full model:`

`full_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=conv_model.input, outputs=predictions)`

`full_model.summary()`

4. Not sure if this works but you can try replacing `softmax` activation function with `sigmoid` activation function in the Output Layer.
5. You can try Regularization Techniques like `Dropout`, `l1_l2 Regularization`, `EarlyStopping`, `BatchNormalization`, etc..

If None of the above steps resolve your problem, please share the complete Reproducible Code so that we can investigate further.